# how to pass structure when call to event occurs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, event-handling

I have an event like `static private void HandleClientEventCB(SPD.SPD_eventType type, SPD.SPD_event this_event, object passback)` in a class `public class SPURTServer`, I need to call this event outside another event
Here the '`**SPD_eventType**`' is enumeration  and `SPD.SPD_event` is a struct like `public struct SPD_event`

```
public struct SPD_event
{
    public string applicationName;
    public string applicationQualifier;
    public object eventData;
    public string host;
    public string objectClass;
    public string objectName;
    public string senderTime;
    public string serverTime;
}
```

So I called like this in outside event like shown below

```
SPURTServer.HandleClientEventCB(Spo.SPDlib.SPD.SPD_eventType.SPD_clientEvent,
    Spo.SPDlib.SPD.SPD_event,null);
```

but it is throwing error:

> 'Spo.SPDlib.SPD.SPD_event' is a 'type', which is not valid in the
>   given context'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Pass Spo.SPDlib.SPD.SPD_event should create instance from structure and pass the instance

```
var sd = new Spo.SPDlib.SPD.SPD_even();
// [Code]

SPURTServer.HandleClientEventCB(Spo.SPDlib.SPD.SPD_eventType.SPD_clientEvent,
    sd ,null);
```

Comment: Thats working fine,only checked any error,,functionality wise i didnt checked yet. Is there any other way to do this any optimized way?